# hashlib writing blockchain in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a blockchain. When running i get the following error:

```
"  File "<ipython-input-3-7d6dab8d7cb5>", line 50
    content_hash= hashlib.sha256(content).hexdigest()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

The line 50 and the lines before are:

This is the code I use

```
#use Pow to find the nonce for the current block
def proof_of_work(self, index, hash_of_previous_block, transactions):
    #try with nonce = 0
    nonce = 0

    #try hashing the nonce together with the hash of the previous block until it is valid
    while self.valid_proof(index, hash_of_previous_block, transactions, nonce) is false:
        nonce += 1
    return nonce

def valid_proof(self, index, hash_of_previous_block, transactions, nonce):
    #create a string containing the hash of the previous block and the block content, including the nonce 
    content ={
f'{index}{hash_of_previous_block}{transactions}{nonce}'.encode()
    #hash using sha256
    content_hash= hashlib.sha256(content).hexdigest()

    #check if the hash meets the difficulty target
    return content_hash[:len(self.difficulty_target)] == self.difficulty_target
    }
```

Comment: you never closed the curly brackets `content ={` until after the `return`, you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually the result of the previous lines. They are not properly closed (you forgot the closing bracket "}") ...so the interpreter is trying to include the next line in with them, and doesn't know how to do it.

Corrected:

```
def valid_proof(self, index, hash_of_previous_block, transactions, nonce):
    #create a string containing the hash of the previous block and the block content, including the nonce 
    content ={
              f'{index}{hash_of_previous_block}{transactions}{nonce}'.encode()
              }
    #hash using sha256
    content_hash = hashlib.sha256(content).hexdigest()
```